# Access SQL - Matching records from two queries

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

**Situation**

I have two queries that select information from various related tables. One selects all the records for `year = 2012` and the other for `year = 2013`

```
SELECT c.Company_ID, c.Company_Name, e.Employee_ID, e.Employee_Name, p.Position
FROM ((tbl_Company AS c
INNER JOIN tbl_Employee AS e ON c.Company_ID = e.Company_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Position AS p ON e.Employee_ID = p.Employee_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Report AS r ON (r.Report_ID = p.Report_ID) AND (c.Company_ID = r.Company_ID)
WHERE (((r.Report_Year)=2012))
```

and

```
SELECT c.Company_ID, c.Company_Name, e.Employee_ID, e.Employee_Name, p.Position
FROM ((tbl_Company AS c
INNER JOIN tbl_Employee AS e ON c.Company_ID = e.Company_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Position AS p ON e.Employee_ID = p.Employee_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Report AS r ON (r.Report_ID = p.Report_ID) AND (c.Company_ID = r.Company_ID)
WHERE (((r.Report_Year)=2013))
```

**Question**

How do I construct a query to return the `Company_ID`, `Company_Name`, `Employee_ID`, `Employee_Name`, and `Position` that match in both queries (i.e. that exists in 2012 AND 2013)?

---

**Update**

Using a sub-query I can select the `company_id` from 2012 only if it is in 2013. How can I now make sure it only selects also the `employee_id` and `position` if these are also the same in 2013 as they are in 2012?

```
SELECT c.Company_ID, c.Company_Name, e.Employee_ID, e.Employee_Name, p.Position
FROM ((tbl_Company AS c
INNER JOIN tbl_Employee AS e ON c.Company_ID = e.Company_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Position AS p ON e.Employee_ID = p.Employee_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Report AS r ON (r.Report_ID = p.Report_ID) AND (c.Company_ID = r.Company_ID)
WHERE r.Report_Year=2013
AND
c.Company_ID IN
(
    SELECT c.Company_ID
    FROM ((tbl_Company AS c
    INNER JOIN tbl_Employee AS e ON c.Company_ID = e.Company_ID) 
    INNER JOIN tbl_Position AS p ON e.Employee_ID = p.Employee_ID) 
    INNER JOIN tbl_Report AS r ON (r.Report_ID = p.Report_ID) AND (c.Company_ID = r.Company_ID)
    WHERE r.Report_Year=2012
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clunky, there might be a more elegant way, but I think this accomplishes what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
(SELECT c.Company_ID, c.Company_Name, e.Employee_ID, e.Employee_Name, p.Position_ID, p.Position
FROM ((tbl_Company AS c
INNER JOIN tbl_Employee AS e ON c.Company_ID = e.Company_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Position AS p ON e.Employee_ID = p.Employee_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Report AS r ON (r.Report_ID = p.Report_ID) AND (c.Company_ID = r.Company_ID)
WHERE (((r.Report_Year)=2012))
)
t1 INNER JOIN

(SELECT c.Company_ID, c.Company_Name, e.Employee_ID, e.Employee_Name, p.Position_ID, p.Position
FROM ((tbl_Company AS c
INNER JOIN tbl_Employee AS e ON c.Company_ID = e.Company_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Position AS p ON e.Employee_ID = p.Employee_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Report AS r ON (r.Report_ID = p.Report_ID) AND (c.Company_ID = r.Company_ID)
WHERE (((r.Report_Year)=2013))
)

t2 ON t1.Company_ID = t2.Company_ID
AND
t1.Employee_ID = t2.Employee_ID
AND t1.Position_ID = t2.Position_ID
```

Comment: Only a slight modification needed but it answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If both of your queries return the same columns, you can use a UNION ALL clause to merge result of the two queries.

```
SELECT c.Company_ID, c.Company_Name, e.Employee_ID, e.Employee_Name, p.Position_ID, p.Position
FROM ((tbl_Company AS c
INNER JOIN tbl_Employee AS e ON c.Company_ID = e.Company_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Position AS p ON e.Employee_ID = p.Employee_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Report AS r ON (r.Report_ID = p.Report_ID) AND (c.Company_ID = r.Company_ID)
WHERE (((r.Report_Year)=2012))
UNION ALL
SELECT c.Company_ID, c.Company_Name, e.Employee_ID, e.Employee_Name, p.Position_ID, p.Position
FROM ((tbl_Company AS c
INNER JOIN tbl_Employee AS e ON c.Company_ID = e.Company_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Position AS p ON e.Employee_ID = p.Employee_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Report AS r ON (r.Report_ID = p.Report_ID) AND (c.Company_ID = r.Company_ID)
WHERE (((r.Report_Year)=2013))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208962%28v=office.12%29.aspx

But you could also use an IN clause to make it simpler and shorter:

```
SELECT c.Company_ID, c.Company_Name, e.Employee_ID, e.Employee_Name, p.Position_ID, p.Position
FROM ((tbl_Company AS c
INNER JOIN tbl_Employee AS e ON c.Company_ID = e.Company_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Position AS p ON e.Employee_ID = p.Employee_ID) 
INNER JOIN tbl_Report AS r ON (r.Report_ID = p.Report_ID) AND (c.Company_ID = r.Company_ID)
WHERE (((r.Report_Year) IN (2012, 2013)))
```

Comment: I think this gives me all the information from both years (and therefore where the information exists in both years it is repeated), whereas I'm after the information that exists in year 1 AND year 2 only.

Comment: If you want unique rows from both years, use the first approach with UNION ALL, and remove the ALL key. UNION, without ALL, will return distinct values from the two datasets.

Comment: @tospig Also, Access seems to have a keyword named DISTINCTROW, non sql standard, which could fit your needs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177882(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: unless I've not understood properly, the UNION (without ALL) still returns all the records from 2012 plus all the records from 2013, whereas I need the records that exist in both years (i.e. if a record is in 2012, but not in 2013 then it is not selected).

Comment: Try SELECT DISTINCT ... and the query with the IN clause

Comment: @Rocky This still gives me records in 2012 even if they don't exist in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

There's intersect, which is similar to union: http://www.sqlguides.com/sql_intersect.php

> SQL INTERSECT is query that allows you to select related information
>   from 2 tables, this is combine 2 SELECT statement into 1 and display
>   it out.
>
> INTERSECT produces rows that appear in both queries.that means
>   INTERSECT command acts as an AND operator (value is selected only if
>   it appears in both statements).

You can make it easier for people to try out your SQL if you use SQL Fiddle.  I setup a very simple table to show an example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/baf67/3

Comment: I didn't think there was an `intersect` in MS Access?